# Specifying system property when starting embedded jetty

Tags: java, web-applications, log4j, jetty

I have a web application which has **log4j** configuration. This configuration is using the system property **catalina.home** when specifying the path where log files are to be placed.

Now I am preparing integration **junit** test suite which loads an **embedded jetty** and loads this web app (then I do my tests using rest calls et all). My problem is that since this web-application is now loaded from jetty *catalina.home* system property is not pre-specified making log files to be stored in the root directory of windows *C:/logs/...*

I need a way to specify *catalina.home* to be used from jetty. Originally I tried using:

```
System.setProperty("catalina.home", "target/jetty/tests/");
```

but this seems to be ignored.

I cannot figure out why the above does not work and how to make it work. Can anyone propose something here? has anyone faced the same problem?

Comment: Does adding a -Dcatalina.home=target/jetty/tests/ when you start your junit test program help?

Comment: ramp 1: Unfortunatelly not. Either way i would prefer that environment is prepared from unit test programatically

Comment: Are you sure that Jetty is using that log4j configuration?  There's no direct support for log4j by Jetty, you might be seeing non-log4j output and assuming its log4j generated.

Comment: I am sure, the name of the log files created, the relative paths and the log message pattern are the ones specified inside log4j.

Comment: correction on my previews message to ramp.
I prefer to specify the properties programatically.
Your solution of  -Dcatalina.home=target/jetty/tests/ works. 
First time i specified it in intelij environmnet attributes and not vm options. Tried again now and this seems to do the trick. is it possible for me to do this programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logging is a special beast, it initializes *very early*, often being one of the very first things that the JVM initializes in your application.

Your use of `System.setProperty("catalina.home", "target/jetty/tests/");` might be too late in the process, as log4j might have already initialized before you even set that property.

For best success with this, you'll want to check the following ...

- Your testcase should not declare a static Logger instance
- Your `System.setProperty` should occurs in a `static { }` block on the testcase
- Perhaps you can get away with a `src/test/resources` replacement (aka override) of your `log4j.properties` (or `log4j.xml`) file for testing reasons, with alternative logging directory paths specified in there.

> **Bonus:** You should look for, and use `${project.basedir}` and `${basedir}` System Properties from the Gradle or Maven environment, and use them to make a fully qualified absolute path for your `System.setProperty()` call, especially if you have a multi-module build, as the relative path will always be from `${user.dir}` (aka PWD) and that doesn't change with a normal build setup.

Comment: src/test/resources replacemen worked.
static block did not work, don't know why, either way i would need logging inside my test cases as well, so i prefered to have a second log4j inside test resources.  

It never occured to me that log4j would initialize before i started jetty since this was the very first thing i was doing, though seems you were right.